# Rule for checking if object is in list

Tags: java, drools, drools-planner

how can I check via Drools Rule Language (DRL) if an object is also part of a list?

Let's take a look at the exam example. Image the situation that an exam has a Room and also a List. Now I want to check, if the Room object is in the List. Is there a function like roomList.contains(rooms) ?

I need this for the DRL.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

For a model like this:

```
class Exam {
    Room room;
...
}
class Room {
    List<Room> roomsList;
...
}
```

Then your rule could look like:

```
rule X
when
    $exam1 : Exam()
    $exam2 : Exam( room.roomsList contains $exam1.room )
then
    // do something
end
```

You can also use "memberOf" operator to check if an element is member of a list, or simply call methods directly if you are using Drools 5.4+.

Answer (score 1):

If you are by any chance taking about the List of Collection framework in java...then yes we do have a method called `frequency()`.

```
List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();

Collections.frequency(l, "room1");
```

Comment: Don't know if that answers the question, but it's good to know!

Comment: But this is no way to check in DRL (Drools Rule Language).

Answer (score 0):

I have the following situation

```
class Exam { 
   Room room;
   ...
}
class Room {
   List<Room> roomList
   ...
}
```

My DRL-Files looks like this:

```
rule "containsRoomOfRoom"
when
    $topicConflict : TopicConflict($leftTopic : leftTopic, $rightTopic : rightTopic)
    $leftExam : Exam(topic == $leftTopic, $period : period, $leftRoom : room)
    $rightExam : Exam(topic == $rightTopic, period == $period, room.roomsList contains $leftRoom)
then
    insertLogical(new IntConstraintOccurrence("roomPenalty", ConstraintType.NEGATIVE_HARD,
            40,
            $leftExam, $rightExam));
```

end

My problem is that I want to check if the room of the leftExam is in the roomList of the rightExam's room.

Sorry for this question but I don'f find any language reference.

Comment: You should have added this info to your original question, not add it as an answer to the question. I edited my previous answer to give you an example similar to this.

Comment: I changed the DRL-File in question above! I get this error: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: cannot invoke getter: getRoom [declr.class: domain.Exam; act.class: domain.Exam] (see trace)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: unable to invoke method: domain.Room.getRoomslist: target of method is null

Comment: Problem seems to be the room.roomsList. Sometimes the roomList is empty. But it never should be null. Maybe drools cannot access the roomslist.

Comment: Make sure you have the proper getXXX() methods in the classes.

Comment: I have a getRoom() and inside of Room I have a getRoomsList(). But it doesn't work for me.

Comment: It seems that there are Exams in the TopicConflict which don't have a room. That must be the reason why Drools could not find the getRoomsList. Maybe it would be easier to write a function in room or exam which I could call from DRL. Is there a solution?